# C# how to create an array of objects?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a following problem. How can I create an array of objects in c#? I'm thinking about this kind of approach what I'm usually using in PHP:

```
$obj1 = new stdClass();
$obj1->first = "first-str";

$obj2 = new stdClass();
$obj2->second = "second-str";

$objarray = array();

$objarray['first'] = $obj1;
$objarray['second'] = $obj2;

echo $objarray['second']->second;
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code converter. Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx). Enjoy.

Comment: why is your sample code all PHP like?

Comment: You have an answer below, OP.  Please mark it as such.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
object[] objs = new object[] {obj1, obj2};
```

for more details about array http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx

You can also find more on http://www.dotnetperls.com/object-array

Answer (score 1):

You can use a List class which can be also extended using Linq library becoming more query/PHP like if you want. First, instantiate a list:

```
List<Object> objects = new List<Object>();
```

The, to fill it, you have to add objects to it:

```
objects.Add(obj1);
objects.Add(obj2);
...
```

Then you can access object instances like so:

```
// First object:
Object objFirst = objects[0];
// Second object:
Object objSecond = objects[1];
```

Or using Linq First(), Last() and so on... of course, to use those functions ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx) a complete list) you have to add System.Linq to your using directives on the top of your source file and make sure you are referencing System.Core library in your project.

Answer (score 0):

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
string[] names = new string[3] {"Matt", "Joanne", "Robert"};

names[1] == "Joanne"
```

From your example, maybe you want to create [Dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)?

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("first", "first-str");
dictionary.Add("second", "second-str");

dictionary["first"] == "first-str"
```

Comment: But is there a simple way to store an object there and access it? if dictionary["first"] has an object, how can I access its properties?

Comment: Generic dictionary exposes properties of an object you store by type. In current example, `dictionary["first"]` would expose all properties of `String`, like `.Lenght`, etc. If you would define dictionary with your specific object, for example `Dictionary<string, SomeObject>`, `dictionary["first"]` would expose interface of `SomeObject`.